# Difference partition_key vs key in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am using camel-kafka version 2.19.2 and I went through the documentation on Camels website - [camel-kafka](http://camel.apache.org/kafka.html) before posting this question here.

I saw that there exists this following example for producing messages.

```
Producing messages:
from("direct:start").process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getIn().setBody("Test Message from Camel Kafka Component Final",String.class);
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY, 0);
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY, "1");
                    }
                }).to("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=test");
```

As you can see, there exists `KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY` and `KafkaConstants.KEY`

Also, for the information, I have a kafka topic with 4 partitions.

I played around with both of them and I understood that `KafkaConstants.KEY` acts as a message key and this key would be used for determining which partition the message goes to.

`KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY`is the one I am confused about as tried setting a partition number but it still sent the messages to all the 4 partitions.

Can anyone specify the difference between these 2 KafkaConstants? And specifically what is `KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY` is used for?

EDIT: Corrected the camel version which is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the github doc of 2.21.0-SNAPSHOT docs:

KEY:
*The record key (or null if no key is specified). If this option has been configured then it take precedence over header link KafkaConstants.KEY*

PARTITION_KEY:
*The partition to which the record will be sent (or null if no partition was specified). If this option has been configured then it take precedence over header link KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY*

Source: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/docs/kafka-component.adoc

For completeness:

In Kafka:

- data is actually a key-value pair
- its storage happens at a partition level

The key is used for intelligent and efficient data distribution within a cluster. Depending on the key, Kafka sends the data to a specific partition and ensures that its replicated as well (configuration).

As you can see in the master branch of Camel-Kafka from Apache Camel project:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaProducer.java#L202-L215

You'll need to specify a key in order to be able to use the partition key you are specifying in your camel route.

Comment: Thanks for the link to github doc - apparently I have to provide a key and then only partition_key can work.
KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY--"kafka.PARTITION_KEY"--Integer--Explicitly specify the partition (only used if the KafkaConstants.KEY header is defined)

So may be update your answer and I can accept it.